# TextView not properly in the center

Tags: android, textview

i want to place a `textview` in the center of a `linearlayout` but i am having problems with it. my `linearlayout` is match_parent in layout_width. `textview` is centered by assigning center to layout_gravity. `textview` is wrap_content in layout_width. here is my xml file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text=" Text"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="monospace" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: in your `LinearLayout` just use `android:gravity="center_horizontal"`.

Answer (score 2):

Two things:
1) set

```
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

in your textview;

2) The second linearlayout (inside) is useless. Just remove it. What's more, if you only have one view, consider using FrameLayout instead of LinearLayout, then use `<merge>` tag to optimize the performance (see details [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/03/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-by.html))

Answer (score 0):

if you want to center the text inside your `TextView` you have to use `android:gravity="center"`

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
android:layout_gravity="center" to 
android:gravity="center"
```

Answer (score 0):

Set these properties in the second Linearlayout.

```
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

Answer (score 0):

to make your textview center set

```
 android:gravity="center"

 android:layout_gravity="center"
```

of your textview.

see the difference here:-

android:gravity :--  sets the gravity of the content of the View its used on.

android:layout_gravity:--   sets the gravity of the View or Layout in its parent.